# How to select only those rows which have different strings in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have this query

```
select p.ID, dp.ID
from MyDB.dbo.Table1 as p
inner join MyDB.dbo.Table2 as dp
on p.Title = dp.Title
```

It compares two strings(varchars) and it gives 113 rows which is the right result.

I am not sure what should I do in TSQL to get only the IDs/rows where p.Title is different then dp.Title.

Using inner join, or left or right join, gives Cartesian product i.e 32000 rows. Something like:

```
select p.ID, dp.ID
from MyDB.dbo.Table1 as p
join MyDB.dbo.Table2 as dp
on p.Title <> dp.Title
```

Should I use some string function to compare strings, or find IS NULL results?
I need to get combinations of p.ID and dp.ID.

Note: The IDs of both table are not linked or known to be identical up-front i.e they are required.

Comment: there should be other condition to join that two tables. can you give some sample data?

Comment: @kirangadhe the first table has 182 rows, the second has 189. I need to find the IDs in both tables which do not have identical Titles(varchar(200)). Title text, words how do I explain it? There could be sub-strings, i.e the title from table1 is sub-string of title in table 2 and vice versa.

Comment: @Vlad, please add sample data (which, given your rep count, should've been included in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query-:

```
select a.ID,b.ID from (
select ID,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) rn 
from MyDB.dbo.Table1 
where ID 
not in (select MyDB.dbo.Table1.ID from MyDB.dbo.Table1 join MyDB.dbo.Table2 on MyDB.dbo.Table1.name=MyDB.dbo.Table2.name) 
)a 
full outer join (
select ID,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) rn 
from MyDB.dbo.Table2 
where ID 
not in (select MyDB.dbo.Table2.ID from MyDB.dbo.Table1 join MyDB.dbo.Table2 on MyDB.dbo.Table1.name=MyDB.dbo.Table2.name) 
) b 
on  a.rn=b.rn
```

SQL Server 2014

Comment: This will list the differing entries of both tables side by side. But what happens if one table has more entries than the other? The "extra" entries will not be listed here.

Comment: Yeah,replace join with full outer join as I updated in above query.

Answer (score 1):

@Vlad, you need to keep the inner join linked by ID first (p.ID=dp.ID). Then in the where clause compare the title like this:

```
select p.ID, dp.ID
from MyDB.dbo.Table1 as p
inner join MyDB.dbo.Table2 as dp
on p.ID=dp.ID
where
    p.Title <> dp.Title
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably searching something like INTERSECT operation

Read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are after. Here is a little fiddle showing the simple join on "inequality" of titles: http://rextester.com/TFIXP19067

```
select p.ID id1, dp.ID id2, p.title t1, dp.title t2
from Table1 as p
inner join Table2 as dp
on p.Title != dp.Title
```

This query will give you a "Cartesian product"-like result. But that is to be expected since you have no further condition on the `JOIN` other than the inequality between the two titles.

Judging by the points given to the other answers I guess you are *not* interested in the Cartesian product solution. In that case maybe a listing of the two tables, one after (below!) the other, limited to those entries that have no equivalence in the other table is a valid solution? Like

```
select * from Table1 where not exists ( select 1 from table2 where table2.title=table1.title );
select * from Table2 where not exists ( select 1 from table1 where table1.title=table2.title )
```

see here: http://rextester.com/RVJRVG86860

**Please note:**

With this query you will get you all differing table entries, regardless of how many there are in each table. The accepted answer (by IShubh) will only list "pairs" of entries and *will not list all entries* if the two tables have *different record counts*.